# Angular Nested subscribe call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an `Ionic` app and trying to implement `Login` module for this using `PHP REST` and `JWT`.

1) User types credentials and api returns with `token`

2) Storing token in `capacitor` storage and intercept next `http` request and add token in header

3) Make call back to api and get logged in user info

4) Store info in `capacitor` storage and proceed further.

Following is the code.

```
loginAction() {
    if (this.validateInputs()) {
        console.log(this.postData);
        this.authService.login(this.postData).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.token) {
                    this.storageService.store('accessToken', res.token);
                    this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe((profile: any) => {
                        console.log(profile);
                        this.storageService
                            .store(AuthConstants.AUTH, profile)
                            .then(res => {
                                this.router.navigate(['home']);
                            });
                    });
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                this.toastService.presentToast('Network Issue.');
            }
        );
    } else {
        this.toastService.presentToast(
            'Please enter email/username or password.'
        );
    }
}
```

The only problem I am having is with the `capacitor` and nested subscribe call.

Sometimes execution to get the `profile` is quick and intercept returns with null value for `accessToken`.

How can I make sure that second `http` call is only executed after the `accessToken` is stored properly?

```
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  // Store the value
  async store(storageKey: string, value: any) {
    const encryptedValue = btoa(escape(JSON.stringify(value)));
    await Storage.set({
      key: storageKey,
      value: encryptedValue
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit the `this.storageService.store()` function?

Comment: Yes, I have added the function in question.

Comment: Please check if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: your answer works the first time and after that same issue. Works first time then log out and when log in, same issue.

Comment: Do you see a valid `res.token` when you login the second time?

Comment: Yes, It automatically logs in on refresh.

Comment: I am sorry but I am out of options.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `storageService.store()` function to return the `Storage.set`. As per the [docs](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage/#method-set-0), it returns a Promise. You could then apply `.then` to your call and handle your operations in the callbacks.

```
export class StorageService {
  constructor() { }

  // Store the value
  public store(storageKey: string, value: any): any {
    const encryptedValue = btoa(escape(JSON.stringify(value)));
    return Storage.set({ key: storageKey, value: encryptedValue });
  }
}
```

And within you loginAction() function:

```
if (res.token) {
  this.storageService.store('accessToken', res.token).then(
    data => {
      this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe((profile: any) => {
          console.log(profile);
          this.storageService
            .store(AuthConstants.AUTH, profile)
            .then(res => { this.router.navigate(['home']); });
      });
    },
    error => { // handle error }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `switchMap` to deal with nested subscribes. Try:

```
loginAction() {
  if (this.validateInputs()) {
    console.log(this.postData());
    this.authService.login(this.postData).pipe(
      // switch context from this observable to another observable based on its value
      switchMap((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.token) {
          this.storageService.store('accessToken', res.token);
          return this.authService.getUserProfile();
        } else {
          return of(null); // import of from rxjs
        }
      }),
      filter((profile: any) => !!filter), // don't include the null emissions in the subscribe block
    ).subscribe((profile: any) => {
      console.log(profile);
      this.storageService.store(AuthConstants.AUTH, profile)
          .then(res => {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
           });
   },
     // can also handle errors using the catchError operator.
     (error: any) => this.toastService.presentToast('Network Issue.');
   );
  } else { 
    this.toastService.presentToast('Please enter email/username or password.');
  }
}
```